# Добавление элемента в ассоциативный массив Jquery

Tags: jquery

Делаю добавление товара в корзину на jquery.

```
function AddGoods(id, title){
    var Goods = localStorage.getItem("Goods");
    if(Goods !== null){
        Goods[id] = title;
        localStorage.setItem("Goods", Goods);
    } else{
        Goods = new Object();
        Goods[id] = title;
        localStorage.setItem("Goods", Goods);
    }
}
```

При добавлении товара в корзину, я передаю id товара и его наименование `AddGoods(3, "Пылесос")` и всё это заношу в память.
При получении значения из памяти `localStorage.getItem("Goods");` я получаю `[object Object]`.

Подскажите как получить нормальный ассоциативный массив или json строку. Или как заносить в память не массив, а например json строку, а затем её разбирать?

Comment: асс.массив это объект, попробуйте извлекать goods.id или Goods[id], не вижу структуры вашего объекта.

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо большое, уже решили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `localStorage` данные хранятся в виде строки, поэтому для сохранения и загрузки объектов, их нужно приводить к строке, например с помощью [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), и получать объект из строки - [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Таким образом приведенный код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
function AddGoods(id, title){
    var Goods = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Goods"));
    if(Goods !== null){
        Goods[id] = title;
        localStorage.setItem("Goods", JSON.stringify(Goods));
    } else{
        Goods = {
          id : title
        };
        localStorage.setItem("Goods", JSON.stringify(Goods));
    }
}
```

И небольшое отступление: в яваскрипте **нет** ассоциативных массивов.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, не успел сам написать по Вашему примеру, как Вы его опубликовали. Респект!