# как прочесть данные из [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Добрый день, у меня есть метод которые генерирует ХТМЛ структуру и записывает его в LocalStorage, но когда я пытаюсь эту структуру получить из LocalStorage, то выдаёт "[object HTMLDivElement]"  и как дальше обработать эту информацию я не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста. Я понимаю, что LocalStorage хранит в себе только стринги, спарсить эту структуру в строку записать в LocalStorage и при получении структуры из LocalStorage путём распарсинга тоже не выходит =(

```
function addItemFromCatalog(imgUrl,descriptionItem,priceItem,colorItem,sizeItem){

     var shoppingBlock = document.createElement('div');
     $(shoppingBlock).addClass("shopping-block"); 
     var shoppingImg = document.createElement('div');
     $(shoppingImg).addClass("shopping-img"); 
     var img = document.createElement('div');
     $(img).addClass("img"); 
     $(img).css("background-image",'url('+imgUrl+')');

     var shoppingPrice = document.createElement('span');
     $(shoppingPrice).addClass("shopping-price"); 
     $(shoppingPrice).text('£ '+priceItem);
     var imgInfo = document.createElement('div');
     $(imgInfo).addClass("img-info"); 
     var description = document.createElement('div');
     $(description).addClass("description"); 
     $(description).text(descriptionItem);
     var color = document.createElement('div');
     $(color).addClass("color"); 
     $(color).text("Color: "+colorItem);
     var imgSize = document.createElement('div');
     $(imgSize).addClass("img-size"); 
     $(imgSize).text('Size: '+sizeItem);
     var quantity = document.createElement('div');
     $(quantity).addClass("quantity"); 
     $(quantity).text('Quantity:');
     var delItem = document.createElement('a');
     $(delItem).addClass("del-item"); 
     $(delItem).attr("href","#0");
     $(delItem).text('Remove item');


     $(imgInfo).append(description);
     $(imgInfo).append(color);
     $(imgInfo).append(imgSize);
     $(imgInfo).append(quantity);
     $(imgInfo).append(delItem);
     $(shoppingImg).append(img);
     $(shoppingImg).append(shoppingPrice);
     $(shoppingBlock).append(shoppingImg);
     $(shoppingBlock).append(imgInfo);

    return shoppingBlock;

}


var output = addItemFromCatalog(imgUrl,descriptionItem,priceItem,colorItem,sizeItem);
localStorage.setItem(id, output);       

console.log(localStorage.id); // вот здесь и получаю [object HTMLDivElement]
```

Скрин для  Grundy :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если это действительно div обьект, то дописать `.innerHTML`, но место где вы "потеряли" обьект, преобразовав его в строку однозначно указать не могу.

Comment: перед тем как я структуру помещаю в LocalStorage она имеет  тип -Object, после того как я получаю её из LocalStorage , то тут она уже [object HTMLDivElement]. Т.е. функция (addItemFromCatalog)вовзращает нужный мне обьект, а получая из ЛокалСтораджа выходит НЕЧТО

Comment: Может вам не нужно **object** помещать  в хранилище - нужно помещать сам текст. А текст внутри div-a - innerHTML.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление элемента в ассоциативный массив Jquery](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496899/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-jquery)

Comment: Все очень просто, элемент `div` при вызове метода `toString()` выдает строку `[object HTMLDivElement]`. Когда вы пытаетесь засунуть элемент в storage, на самом деле туда уходит вот эта описывающая элемент строка, никаких данных в ней уже больше нет. Как правильно поместить элемент в storage, смотрите в ответе @Grundy.

Comment: Grundy -  только решение не подходит, в целом почитаю про иннерХТМЛ и оутерХТМЛ

Comment: @user3319778, решение основывается на том, _что именно_ нужно хранить. В любом случае html элементы нельзя сериализовать. Максимум можно получить их разметку. Но наверняка даже это не нужно, и нужно просто хранить объект по которому этот див можно построить, и вот тут уже вполне себе подходит ответ по ссылке на дубликат

Comment: Grundy - переписал всё на  JSON.parse и JSON.stringify и в итоге получаю   [object Object]  - как у автора той темы =) Я понял что ошибка видимо в создании самой  структуры ....

Comment: @user3319778, если получаешь `[object Object]` - То очевидно не выполняешь _JSON.stringify_ перед сохранением

Comment: Grundy - я добавил в свой вопрос скриншот что б показать что я выполняю JSON.stringify перед сохранением

Comment: @user3319778, стоит перечитать мой комментарий выше: _В любом случае html элементы нельзя сериализовать. Максимум можно получить их разметку._

Answer (score 3):

> [В *LocalStorage* можно хранить **только** строки.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Для хранения объектов, их нужно *предварительно сериализовать*, например использовав [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Для случая с дивом, нужно вообще брать либо [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), либо [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Но наверняка даже это не нужно, и нужно просто хранить объект по которому этот див можно построить.

Comment: а какой вид имеет примерно такой обьект?

Comment: @user3319778, по сути нужно просто сохранить параметры для функции `imgUrl,descriptionItem,priceItem,colorItem,sizeItem` чтобы потом просто вызвать эту функцию с этими параметрами и получить тот же самый див, с которым можно работать. но что-то конкретнее можно сказать только узнав что вообще в коде происходит и зачем

Comment: А такое возможно скажем если у меня есть 3 страницы, на первой странице пользователь выбирает товар и попадает на 2ю страницу,  на которой он редактирует товар и потом переходит на 3ю страницу - корзину, в которой я и отображаю товар, я пробовал хранить параметры для функции в обьекте но получается что они перетирают друг друга когда пользователь добавляет второй товар и третий и т.д., поэтому я решил хранить данные в Локал Сторадже

Comment: @user3319778, ну так сериализовать можно и массив объектов, не только отдельный объект

Comment: а как после сериализации получить данные в первоначальном типе данных , в котором они были помещены в ЛокалСторадж до сериализации?  выход один только, через JSON.parse() и никак иначе?:

Comment: @user3319778, после сериализации получается _строка_. по этому логично, что для того, чтобы работать с объектом, его надо получить с помощью JSON.parse

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44314/discussion-between-user3319778-and-grundy).